# How does one exclude a single image, or a set of images from a cache control policy?

Tags: caching, header, seo, cdn, cache-control

I'm looking to set a cache control policy on some of the images on my website to appease the Google lords, however I don't want all the images on my website to be cached. While I'm a bit fuzzy on how the Cache control policy works, my understanding is that I place it in the header of my page, and all the images, JS, and CSS on the page gets cached for the set amount of time specified.

But if I set my cache control policy to:

```
Cache-Control: Max-age=31536000
```

How do I keep a specific asset or assets from being cached for that years time. I have banners and images on my page that are updated every so often that I can't have cached and left static for a years time.

Comment: What kind of code are you look for?  Are you setting cache control headers from code in a specific language and framework?   Are you using `.htaccess` to set cache control? It is impossible to answer your question without knowing these details.

Comment: Are you asking how to conditionalize the cache control header for different files, or are you asking what a more reasonable value should be?

Answer (score 1):

***While I'm a bit fuzzy on how the Cache control policy works, my understanding is that I place it in the header of my page, and all the images, js, and css on the page gets cached for the set amount of time specified.***

No, cache headers only apply to the specific response being returned, not any other resources linked to by the page. All the other assets need their own cache headers, which of course allows you to choose a specific cache time for each resource.

Comment: Can you give me an example of this being used in code? I'm now not sure how to implement a cache control policy in this case. Any insight would be appreciated. There seems to be very little information that I can understand online.

Comment: @Deo3560: `Cache-Control` is a header that gets added to your response. How it's configured depends entirely on what server or service is sending that response. Apache has its way, nginx has its way, all the CDNs have their own way, etc. The [Google caching guide](https://web.dev/http-cache/) links directly to the [configuration instructions](https://web.dev/http-cache/#response-headers) for the most popular servers.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you want to cache images?  Images at static objects; if you're creating different images then they should have different names, or extension types.

With that being said, if you're using a a CDN, most allow for configuration of custom TTLs on resources.  I'd recommend reaching out to CDN support to figure out how to set up rule.

Also, most common applications (Rails, Express, etc) and Web Servers (Nginx, Apache) allow for overriding the headers as well.  Server side configuration may be more flexible then the CDN option since you control the logic and not dependent on a third party controlling it.

Here's a [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control) to Mozilla's spec on the cache-control header

Comment: its not that I don't want to cache images, I do. that's the whole point of this, I want to, but not all. The ones I don't to, like my hero-carousel, that changes frequently, I can't have cached, or else things like sales or promotional materials will never update. Unless I'm very confused about how content-control policies work...

Comment: in that case i would recommend utilizing CMS capabilities to rename files, or append a unique query param (maybe an epoch timestamp of publish time).  Most CDNs are configured to create unique caches based on full URI (including query params). This will ensure that you have the latest image and you dont need to create custom rules anywhere (since you can have a single caching rule).